# JQuery Datepicker for Simpleform just like in ActiveAdmin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datepicker, activeadmin

In Active Admin I can do the following, which will render a nice Datepicker, rather than a set of Dropdown fields:

```
f.input :some_date, :as => :datepicker
```

[image]

However, when I do this with my custom form, I get the following error:

```
No input found for datepicker
```

However, this does not work outside of Active-Admin. Is there an easy way to do the same with any simple_form-based form?

Comment: This functionality seems to be brocken in the latest version `3.1.5` of formtastic. See https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/1252

Answer (score 0):

You could do what I do with simple form: (includes set as today button =P)

Add the javascript for the datepicker fields...

```
// my_javascript.js
$('#position_buy_date').datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
$('#set_buy_date').on('click', function (){
    $('#position_buy_date').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

Modify the input field to be a string

`<%= f.input :buy_date, as: :string, hint: button_tag('Set as today', type: 'button', class: 'btn', id: 'set_buy_date') %>`